# More user-friendly Input parameter for function in developing R package

Tags: r, user-interface, package, rstudio, user-input

I am making a package where a summarization report is generated. I have one function called makeSum that requires many input data and will output the summary report. However, there are 6 different output summary reports that can be made.

Since there are so many other functions in the package, I thought it would make the most sense to have one function (makeSum) with a parameter (sumType) that has 6 possible string options (each one indicating the type of summary to be made - "aBShort", "aBLong", "gB", "eAShort", "eALong", "eB"), rather than have 6 different functions ("makeSumABShort", "makeSumABLong", "makeSumGB", "makeSumEAShort", "makeSumEALong", "makeSumEB").

I am trying to determine if there are steps I can take to render it easier for a user to provide the correct string for the sumType parameter when running the makeSum function (without having to memorize the string name, as they will be long).

For instance, when using RStudio, if I know roughly what a function name is (say makeSum), then I can start to type it into the console, hit tab, and have autofill suggestions. If I have a particular parameter for that function (say sumType), then I can also type it into the console, hit tab, and have autofill suggestions. Is it possible to do something similar when there are exactly 6 string options that can be used for that parameter? To keep with the example, if I were to type:

```
makeSum(data1 = myDF1, data2 = myDF2, sumType = )
```

and hit tab, then I would have the six possible string options ("aBShort", "aBLong", "gB", "eAShort", "eALong", "eB") listed for me.

As of now, a user would have to run help(makeSum), and scroll through the help manual to determine what exactly the name of the string they wanted to use was for the sumType parameter.

I did consider using numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) instead of long strings, but I found the long strings made more clear to fully specify the content of the 6 summarization reports.

Any suggestions on how to make this aspect more user-friendly would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my MWE:

```
#' Generate summarization report
#'
#' Generates one of six possible types of summarization reports
#'
#' @param data1 first input
#' @param data2 second input
#' @param sumType type of summarization report. One of the following six string possibilities must be specified ("aBShort", "aBLong", "gB", "eAShort", "eALong", "eB"). "aBShort" means short version of alpha and beta summarization. "ABLong" mean long version of alpha and beta summarization. "gB" means gamma and beta summarization. "eAShort" means short version of epsilon and alpha summarization. "eALong" means long version of epsilon and alpha summarization. "eB" means epsilon and beta summarization.
#' @export

#'
makeSum =
  function(data1=NULL, data2=NULL, sumType=NULL){
...
}
```

Comment: Look at code for `chooseCRANmirror`

Comment: @42 Thanks for the help. I looked at chooseCRANmirror but am unsure of how that relates to my question, and in what way it will make the parameter type easier for users in this scenario? I may just be missing the main theme here. Could you explain a bit to get me in the right direction? I would be grateful for that!

Comment: It displays a menu of options using functions from the `tk`-family. First you look at `chooseCRANmirror`, which calls `.chooseMirror`, which then calls `menu()`. I suppose I could have suggested just looking at `?menu`, but at the time I suggested it, I had not yet traversed the calling sequence..

Comment: Thank you! From reading the ?menu, it truly seems like what I am aiming for! However, I tried to implement it by changing my line in my code: function(data1=NULL, data2=NULL, sumType=menu(("aBShort", "aBLong", "gB", "eAShort", "eALong", "eB"))). I could get the summarization reports to still run by having lines to translate these strings to the appropriate tasks. However, when I ran the function as a user, I could not get the menu to list options. For instance, I typed: makeSum(data1 = myDF1, data2 = myDF2, sumType = ), and did not get the menu. Am I applying the menu function correctly?

Comment: You need to create vector of choices. See below:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> mychoice <- function() {sumType=menu(c("aBShort", "aBLong", "gB", "eAShort", "eALong", "eB")); print(sumType)}
> mychoice()

1: aBShort
2: aBLong
3: gB
4: eAShort
5: eALong
6: eB

Selection: 4
[1] 4
```

Unless you want a default type to be specified, you do not need a parameter in the formals of your function.